# Build UI based on object with nested objects arrays

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering if there is a way on angular to build an user interface based on an object.

I'm aware of the ng-repeat sections, that works well for simple arrays and or objects containing elements of the same type. But I want to know if there is a way to build dinamically an UI with objects that contains arrays of objects and arrays as elemets.

Here is an example object:

```
{ name: 'daMan', 
  likings: ['bicicle','running','sleeping'], 
  family: [ {name: 'Ted', type: 'son'},{name: "Marga, type:'Wife'}]
}
```

I want to display that as a table, where the arrays with strings, are lists of input elements, and the array of objects are simple forms where you can input values for the property names. Also I want to put a plus button on those properties that are an array, so you can add an element of the same type to the array.

Is this too complex? In some way, it sounds like a JSON editor.

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes it can be done.  What  you want to do sounds similar to this AngujarJS Form Builder: http://selmanh.github.io/angularjs-form-builder/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it all yourself. You can do everything that you asked about using nested ng-repeat. Every time you encounter an array in your object even if nested you can use an ng-repeat. I created a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/codekhalifah/pen/RWLoWp) for you to view.

Attach the data to the scope object in the form of an array of objects:

```
$scope.items = [
   { name: 'daMan', 
     likings: ['bicicle','running','sleeping'], 
     family: [ {name: 'Ted', type: 'son'},{name: "Marga, type:'Wife'}]
   },
   { name: 'daMan', 
     likings: ['bicicle','running','sleeping'], 
     family: [ {name: 'Ted', type: 'son'},{name: "Marga, type:'Wife'}]
   }
];
```

Each time you hit an array in your object you can use the ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" class="container">
    Username: {{item.name}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="liking in item.likings">{{liking}}</li>
    </ul>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
       <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td>Type</td>
       </tr>
       <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="member in item.family">
           <td>{{member.name}}</td>
           <td>{{member.type}}</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. I should have specified that I want it to be dynamically generated. I mean that I don't know which properties will hold an array and which ones will have just a regular string.